# 404 when creating Web Service with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

In order to implement a REST Web Service, I am following this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

and made those steps:

1. creating a dynamic web project
2. copying [jersey files](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) to WEB-INF/lib as shown below

[image]

3. creating a java class (same as in the example) into this package **com.vogella.jersey.first** which registers its methods for GET and it supposes to return text/xml/html
4. copying my web.xml as here

[image]

Running my web app, I am getting 404 and this exception:

```
 ... Marking servlet Jersey REST Service as unavailable

ott 30, 2015 9:31:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/com.vogella.jersey.first] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5543)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ott 30, 2015 9:31:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ott 30, 2015 9:31:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
ott 30, 2015 9:31:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
info: Server startup in 1506 ms
```

- What does that mean?
- How to fix it?

Comment: can you check if the jar is deployed in the deployment folders in the application server.

Comment: please where is that folder? In eclipse or in the tomcat path?

Comment: Check the jar file in tomcat folder where your application is deployed /webapps/<yourapp>/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: thanks @VivekSingh no, is not deployed anything on the tomcat that I am using

Comment: The app is deployed, just not to your local tomcat. I guess Eclipse launches its own internal instance. If the app wasn't deployed, you wouldnt get that error. The error is saying that the class you declared in your web.xml doesn't exist. It doesn't exist because you're using the wrong version of Jersey libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you not notice that that jars from the Vogella tutorial are completely different from the jars in your project? The jars in your project are from Jersey 1.x. The tutorial is using Jersey 2.x. Therefore the configuration in the web.xml is for 2.x, which is different from 1.x

You can download Jersey 2.x [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). Click the JAX-RS 2.0 RI Bundle link. All the jars you need are in there. Note that that there is no JSON/POJO support jars in that distribution. You will need to find those separately.

Make sure to remove all the jars currently in your project, as they may conflict with the newer version.

Comment: thanks @peeskillet, I fixed the jar ri but I am still getting a 404

Comment: Because you named you project `com.vogella.jersey.first` (which will be default be the context path), the URI should be `http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello`

Comment: it works this, I was misled by the eclipse page that loads after run the project